# Unified Service Desk condition comparison issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, unified-service-desk

I am using Unified Service Desk. The task was, when clicking on contact from other entities, show existing contact tab if this contact already opened or create new session if contact is different from already opened. Thanks to this article I found how to get URL of clicked contact in place type. But using conditions on window navigation rules or actions, can not correctly compare contactid from clicked contact and in context contact.Id. In case with condition on action call ( which is hanged on window navigation rule), script below always gives me true and if I change == to != it also gives true (tried === and !== as well). Action Call is a DisplayMessage with this properties:

Condition:

```
var targetId =$Expression(/%257b([a-z0-9\-]+)\%257d/i.exec('[[URL]]')[1]);
var existingId = "[[contact.Id]]";
targetId == existingId
```

Data

```
text=$Expression(/%257b([a-z0-9\-]+)\%257d/i.exec('[[URL]]')[1]) + [[contact.Id]]
```

Result message box:

5EE7F26E-1976-E711-8100-5065F38B74A1 + 5CE7F26E-1976-E711-8100-5065F38B74A1

And once more, if I change condition to targetId != existingId message still appears if Ids are equal:

5EE7F26E-1976-E711-8100-5065F38B74A1 + 5EE7F26E-1976-E711-8100-5065F38B74A1

So looks like condition works incorrectly. Maybe someone have met such behavior and resolved it somehow, I am really stuck in it.

Comment: I wonder if your condition is False (instead of false), and whether USD would consider that to be a string with value (effectively true).  Can you copy Target ID to $Context?  If so, then you may be able to use it in Action Call condition comparisons, like a simple:[[$Context.ClickedContactId]] == [[contact.Id]]
I like to set up batches of sub-action-calls that temporarily create $Context values, evaluate them against my [[entity.field]], and overwrite them with empty strings afterwards.

Comment: Try adding quotes (or removing quotes) around your ID strings. USD is weird and in some cases requires quotes for conditions, but in other cases does not.

Comment: Yes, there is a mess with quotes for different places in USD, but also need to consider point, that only IE compatible code works. Ended up with action and condition in it: var targetUrl ='[[URL]]';
var existingId = '[[contact.Id]]';
var position = targetUrl.indexOf(existingId);
position < 0